# Not getting both coordinates when using cluster_centers_

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

When I run the following

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(PR,PG,test_size=0.4,random_state = 0)
xtrain.append(NR)
ytrain.append(N19G)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
kmeans.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

my output is:

```
[[20.        ]  
[ 2.82666667]  
[ 9.95918367]  
[ 0.17924528]  
[4.23214286]]
```

I am not getting the Y- Coordinate. Do I need to merge my xtrain and ytrain lists?

Comment: What's the shape of `xtrain`? What is NR, N19G?

Comment: so x train is a Dataframe, NR and N19G are lists

Comment: what does `xtrain.shape` return ? probably something like (N, 1) so you have only one feature thus only one cluster coordinate ...

Comment: @seralouk I think there s a simpler explanation for the question (see answer). Χαιρετισμούς ;)

Comment: @desertnaut καλησπερα. indeed this could be the case.

Answer (score 2):

As the term *unsupervised* clearly implies, k-means, like any other clustering (i.e. unsupervised) algorithm, **knows (and cares) nothing about labels**, like `y_train` here; it only cares about the *features* (`x_train`).

In fact, including the labels `y` in `kmeans.fit()`, as you do here, makes absolutely no difference; the option is there only for API consistency reasons, as clearly indicated in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit):

> **y : *Ignored***
>
> Not used, present here for API consistency by convention.

So, calling `kmeans.fit(xtrain,ytrain)` is equivalent to `kmeans.fit(xtrain)`, and the behavior you describe is as expected.

> Do I need to merge my xtrain and ytrain lists?

Although from a purely *programming* point of view you could certainly do it, it would not make any sense from a *methodology* perspective; as already said, clustering models are not supposed to take into account the labels.